# Html/Css Force wrap number displayed in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to force wrap text even number fit to the width I defined.

```
<tr style="font-size:22px" id="id_step">
    <td valign="top" style="width: 1190px">
     <img src="file://#step_image" width="140" style="float: right"/>
        <strong>#step_no</strong>
        #step_text
    </td>        
</tr>
```

When I replace **#step_text** by **111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111110000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444499999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999**

It can't be wrappep. Can you help me, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write:

```
td{word-break:break-word;}
```

[DEMO here.](http://jsfiddle.net/tGPsn/)

Comment: But if I have a picture, the string of number is pushed down, I want it wrap the image, too

Answer (score 2):

Use this style like below :

***css***

```
word-break: break-all
```

use Inline styles like below

`<td style="word-break: break-all">`

Answer (score -1):

You can try white-space:nowrap in  :

```
<td valign="top" style="width: 1190px; white-space:nowrap;">
```

Comment: No, it can't wrap as I wish